# how to find string ("as is" - no substring) from line?

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, match

i'm new with python and wants to do the following:

1. search inside text to check if token exists
2. token cannot be substring inside the text - must be "as is" (string11111 is not string1)

   ```
   file = "string11111 aaaaa string1 bbbbb"
   token = "string1"

   if token in file:
       print "NOT yay!"
   ```
3. token needs to be searched for end position to beginning (reversly)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what the last item in your list means? If you're just checking if the token is in the bigger string, it doesn't matter what direction you're searching in (the target is either found or not). Do you expect to get more information as your results, like all matches or the location of the last match? Is your token always a simple string, rather than some kind of pattern (e.g. a regex)?

Comment: You need the index of the last item?

Answer (score 2):

First tokenize your `file` variable

```
tokens = file.split()
```

Then look for your token

```
if token in tokens:
    # do your thing
```

Comment: there is no elegant way to do it? if the token is "string1" and the token[0] is "string111" it will match...that not what i'm looking for

Comment: @user1596023, I don't believe the code in the answer does what you think.  'string111' does not equal 'string1' so it won't match (i.e. it won't execute 'do your thing').  However, this does not search in reverse, which was another one of your requirements.

Comment: Well if you're using the example you provided, there is a 'string1' token. So this will obviously find a match, right?

Answer (score 0):

hoping the below solution meets your need -

```
file = "string11111 aaaaa string1 bbbbb"
token = "string1"

token_matched = [file_token for file_token in file.split()[::-1] if token in file_token and len(token) == len(file_token)]

print('Matched tokens (reverse order) - ', token_matched)
if len(token_matched) > 1:
    # Reoccurs more than one time which means the token could be sub-string
    print("NOT yay!")
elif len(token_matched) == 1:
    # Matches only time definitely it could not be the sub-string
    print("OHH yay!")
else:
    print("Token not exist in file.")
```

Comment: i want to check if string1 exist and disregard about string11111, they both ocntains the token indeed but only string1 is the exact set of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, using regex

```
file = "string11111 aaaaa string1 bbbbb"[::-1]
token = "string1"
regex = r"\b" + re.escape(token) + r"\b"
match = re.findall(regex , file)[0]

if match in file:
    print "NOT yay!"
```